# How do I return the entire set / array using NSPredicate?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm building a `carArray` and want to filter the contents conditionally, using an `NSPredicate`, like so:

```
NSPredicate *pred;
switch (carType) {
  case FreeCar:
    pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"premium = NO"];
    break;
  case PremiumCar:
    pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"premium = YES"];
    break;
  default:
    pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SOME PREDICATE THAT RETURNS EVERYTHING"];
    break;
}
self.carArray = [aCarArrayIGotFromSomewhere filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

My question is, what is the correct syntax for the value I've stubbed in as `SOME PREDICATE THAT RETURNS EVERYTHING` which returns all of the instances in the array / set?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To return all of the contents a given array / set:

Swift:

`NSPredicate(value: true)`

for example:

`let array : NSArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
array.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)`

yields:

`["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`

To exclude all of the contents a given array / set:

Swift:

`NSPredicate(value: false)`

for example:

`let array : NSArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: false)
array.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)`

yields:

`[]`

Comment: Unfortunately the relevant docs are rather silent on how to use this TRUEPREDICATE thingie. I can't make it out in any case. So, I searched Stack Overflow and for once got no wiser :(

Comment: I second the need for an example.  I tried the intuitive solution (i.e. just passing TRUEPREDICATE as the format string and I got an NSInvalidArgumentException).

Comment: instead of [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"] you could do [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES]

Answer (score 4):

For always true or always false you can use `[NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES]` or `[NSPredicate predicateWithValue:NO]`.